# Strange gradle build error with no context

Tags: android-studio, gradle, libgdx

```
Error:com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects.lastGradleSyncFailed(Lcom/intellij/openapi/project/Project;)Z
```

This is all it is saying, nothing else. My gradle sync's are going through without any errors as well, this just happens when I try to run the program. Has anyone an idea of where to start? Thanks,

EDIT: This is the error line in my log:

```
2017-03-07 15:10:00,830 [1055192]INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects.lastGradleSyncFailed(Lcom/intellij/openapi/project/Project;)Z
```

EDIT2: Here is the log file

```
017-03-07 15:10:00,773 [1055135]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2017-03-07 15:10:00,829 [1055191]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home 
2017-03-07 15:10:00,830 [1055192]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects.lastGradleSyncFailed(Lcom/intellij/openapi/project/Project;)Z
at org.robovm.idea.components.RoboVmBuildProcessParametersProvider.getVMArguments(RoboVmBuildProcessParametersProvider.java:60)
at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.launchBuildProcess(BuildManager.java:1136)
at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.lambda$null$11(BuildManager.java:730)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.runFirstTaskThenPollAndRunRest(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:178)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$000(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:40)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:197)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2017-03-07 15:10:00,877 [1055239]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2017-03-07 15:10:00,928 [1055290]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -     COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 1; warnings: 0 took 165 ms: 0 min 0sec
```

Comment: Make sure android sdk is upto date

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: It resolved for a bit after uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio, however it just came back. I don't have any idea how this replicated either.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this thread

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160899

May be uninstalling android-studio-unit-test-plugin resolved this issue.